# Data table action buttons are not getting disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to disable some action buttons using jquery with css classes. It's working in normal pages, but it's not working for datatables.

I don't know why, I got really stuck. I am showing my code below.

If anybody knows, please help me

```
$(document).ready(function(){

         $("a.button").addClass('btn disabled');
          $("a.remove").addClass('ui-state-disabled'); // this is my datatable remove button with class remove
         $("a.button").css("margin-top", "-5px"); 
         $("a.button").css("pointer-events", "none");
   $('[type=file]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

Comment: please post full code and before disabling button create the datatable first.

Comment: maybe your code overwrite by some codes in datatable.js file

Comment: data table is already done, i am trying to handle those buttons from normal jquery. remove buttons in datatable have class remove,and edit have class edit. i just want to disable it

Comment: @NasserAliKarimi  i only want to disable edit and delete icons in dattable for some users. so i think it can be done from document,ready itself

Comment: I would not suggest disabling buttons as a way of restricting those button use. Advanced users may simply re-enable those buttons and click them. I would rather render page contents (including DataTable and its controls) based on user permissions.

Comment: are you calling your datatable function before ready function and how?

Comment: i am writing this code in a common js file and datatable js is in another file

Comment: but in commonJs file it is in ready function or some normal function
because 2 ready function in one html is bad practice.

Comment: ThinkTAank  i will change it,please give soluitons for this issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you, by any chance, examined [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/) article?

Because, `$('{myButtonSelector}').prop('disabled', true)` works perfectly on my DataTables